# Is there any way to customize Eclipse Look & Feel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know that we can customize the appearance of editors, using

**Window> Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts**

But can I go further with an inbuilt eclipse feature (Without using a third party plugin like Jeeeyul)

To make more clear, I want something like;

- Change the fonts in eclipse tabs, view parts...
- Make all tab corners square rather than rounded corners.
- Increase tab spacing and apply a flat color
- ..etc

Something like, create/update a `.css` file in the eclipse installation is also fine.

Or else, develop a plugin using `org.eclipse.ui.themes` extension point is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change fonts and colours by modifying the existing Eclipse CSS files (or defining a new theme to avoid changing system files). The standard CSS files are in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plugin directory in the Eclipse installation.

Changing the shape of tabs would require writing a new tab renderer which you can specify in the CSS. For example in my RCP I use this:

```css
.MPartStack 
{
  swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://greg.music.ui/greg.music.ui.css.CTabRendering2');
  swt-unselected-close-visible: true;
  swt-shadow-visible: false;
  swt-mru-visible: false;
  swt-simple: true;
  swt-mru-visible: false;
  swt-minimize-visible: false;
  swt-maximize-visible: false;
}
```

This requires you to write a plugin.

Other, more extreme, changes to the UI can be made by using custom renderers for UI elements. This would require building a new Eclipse RCP product based on the normal Eclipse RCP and specifying a renderer factory using the `rendererFactoryUri` product property.